# Zoom on HTML Image Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know how to zoom-in/magnify an HTML Image Map in the same style as [jQZoom](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/)?

I've tried using/adapting the jQZoom code but end up losing the Image Map links and just linking to the larger image.

Any ideas/help greatly appreciated, S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Bezoom http://benjaminmock.de/bezoom-jquery-plugin/

Bezoom uses the img tag to apply the zoom, the the script seems pretty straightforward:

```
var img = $(this).find('img');

var imgSmallHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
var imgSmallWidth = $(this).find('img').width();
```

You could change these and some other thingies in the code to apply the effect to any other element such as a div. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks, S. I did get this working, but as soon as I dropped it into my html page it stopped working. Managed to track it down to a css error - the two outermost containing divs had position:relative which seemed to break it. Ended up going back to jQZoom and adjusting the Jquery to work off the 'rel'.

Comment: Awesome! So glad it worked! Now I'm curious, is it uploaded somewhere I can see it?